# Missing '/' in static path using django and nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx

I'm very new to django and nginx. When hitting `/domain/admin`
The admin page loads but without css.

After checking the logs by hitting this command `tail -30 /var/log/nginx/error.log`

output: `/usr/local/apps/appname/staticrest_framework/js/prettify-min.js`

I've found out that `/` is missing in the `staticrest_framework` the expected output should be `/usr/local/apps/appname/static/rest_framework/js/prettify-min.js`

**Here is my settings.py:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/usr/local/apps/appname/static/'
```

**nginx config:**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/local/apps/appname/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:9000/;
        proxy_set_header  Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For     $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_redirect    off;
    }
}
```

Please help, how do I add `/` in the middle of `static` and `rest_framework` path?

Comment: Seems like you're building static URLs manually somewhere in your views/templates/serializers instead of using built-in functions. There is no "put slash in the middle" Django option so keep debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my nginx config to this. And now it works. Basically changing `alias` to `root`.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        location /static {
            root /usr/local/apps/appname/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:9000/;
            proxy_set_header  Host                $host;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For     $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
            proxy_redirect    off;
        }
    }
```